# How to FlipFromLeft?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, flip

```
UIImageView * frontImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage 
                                                                   imageNamed:@"view.png"]];

UIView * containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frontImageView.bounds];
containerView.center = self.view.center;

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
[containerView addSubview:frontImageView];

UIImageView * backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage 
                                                                  imageNamed:@"view.png"]];
backImageView.center = frontImageView.center;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                       forView:containerView 
                         cache:YES];
[frontImageView removeFromSuperview];
[containerView addSubview:backImageView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

i wanna Flip the containerView,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843534/flip-view-iphone) is a similar post about the same problem. @Jason Harwig suggests that you try:

> Try using `self.view.superview` in the animation transition view of the
>   `showMoreInfo:`

***EDIT:*** Looking at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321346/subviews-not-displaying-during-flip-transition), it seems as though adding the subview *BEFORE* commiting the animations is the problem. Why don't you try that?

Hope that Helps!

Comment: sorry,i don't want the superview,i just want to flip the containerView

Answer (score 0):

dont use

> [frontImageView removeFromSuperview];

in this function. What happens is before the animations happen, your view gets removed from superview. Hence, no animation. Instead use this.

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeImageView)];
```

and make another method,

```
-(void) removeImageView
{
        if([yourImageView superview])
            [yourImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: [containerView sendSubviewToBack:frontImageView];                    i just try like this ,but there was no animation:

Answer (score 0):

Set containerView's frame properly.You have set it to frontImageView.bounds that is not right.

Comment: Dear Hitesh, i change it ,but not help.